# Use legend in matlab

Tags: matlab, legend

can anyone tell me why my `legend` gives me error meassage:

```
b=data(:,1);    
hold on
plot(b,a,'r');
plot(b,a1,'b');
hold off
legend('L','S');
```

the code works well without `legend`, but can not see the legends in the figure.

**Edit**
This is the error message I get:

```
Attempted to access legend(76,83);
index out of bounds because size(legend)=[1,10]
```

Comment: What error message are you getting? Can you specify an example `a`, `b`, and `a1` similar to what you're using for the variables?

Comment: Attempted to access legend(76,83); index out of bounds because size(legend)=[1,10].

Comment: Don't you have a variable named `legend` in your code? Well you shouldn't, change its name and it works like a charm. `legend` is a pretty robust command.

Comment: Those are the char values for L and S. Do you have a variable specified as legend? It would be trying to index it for that call.

Comment: No, I don't have any variable which is called legend

Comment: You mean when you type `legend` in command window, it prints nothing (especially a `1x10` array)? If so then you have created it mistakenly, type `clear legend` to remove it from `workspace`.

Comment: Hi, thank you.. I got the answer down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a variable named `legend` in your workspace. MATLAB interprets `legend('L','S')` as an index call of the character values of 'L' (76) and 'S' (83) to the variable `legend`.

Rename legend to something else and make sure you clear it before running your code again.

In the future, if you're unsure if a variable name you're using is a pre-existing MATLAB function, you can always type, `help functionName` into the workspace.

Comment: ok, it works now.. thanks sooo much :).. I changed L and S name

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
b=data(:,1);
plot(b,a,'r');
hold on
plot(b,a1,'b');
legend('L','S'); 
hold off
```